# Netcat forward host lookup: Unknown host, but I can ping

Tags: ip, ping, netcat, traceroute

dears!! I'm trying to use netcat for remote connect in my computer and I'm facing a problem here.

I`m using two machines and both have a VM running Kali Linux. One of them is the linstener and the other the connector, the listener is connected in my network, but the other is connected in my mobile phone hotspot for simulate connection over networks.

When I put the listener to listen using

```
sudo nc -nlvp PORT
```

I get:

> Listening on 0.0.0.0 PORT

But when I start my connector using:

```
sudo nc IP PORT
```

I get:

> IP: forward host lookup failed: Unknown host

I can ping each VM using CLI, can access internet, can use traceroute, but I can't connect using netcat.

Do you can help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you really entering the IP address or a hostname? To completely disable address resolution for (openbsd) netcat, you can type `-n`: `nc -n IP PORT`.